# what is reconstruction of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am a high school student prepairing for IMO, and while studying I came accross a doubt. There is a question

> A is a set containing n elements. a subset P of A is selected. The set A is reconstructed by replacing the elements of P. A subset Q is again selected. Find number of ways to select P and Q such that P Intersection Q contains exactly R elements

Here in this question, I was unable to understand the line

> The set A is reconstructed by replacing the elements of P

What does reconstruction of set mean here?

I tried to search on the web alot about my question, but was unable to fing anything useful thanks in advance :)

Comment: In context, this appears not to be a very precise mathematical term. The question does not appear to depend on what happens to the elements of $P$. It's possible they don't mean anything at all by it. Where did you see this question?

Comment: @Jackson I found this question in IOQM classes of a coaching institute. IOQM is an exam taken in India which acts as a qualifier for International mathematical olympiad.

Comment: I see. To me it looks like the most sensible way to approach the question is to assume that no change at all is made after selecting $P$. If the coaching institute that gave you the question hasn't previously given a definition for reconstruction, then I don't know where else you would be able to find one—it's certainly not a universally understood term in elementary set theory. I'm really not sure what you could do with the elements of $P$ that would affect the answer (as compared to ignoring the part where it says $A$ is reconstructed), but with the problem overall being well-posed.

Comment: In context.... I don't think it means any anything.  Imagine you were 7 years old and learning about sets for the first time.  You have a set $A$ with $n$ elements.  You take as subset $P$.  Now a seven-year old might think you mean you are taking the elements of $P$ *out* of $A$ and so $A$ somehow no longer has those elements in it anymore because you took them out.  (But that's not how math works; $A$ is still the same set with all the elements still in it).  So now the teacher is saying "take the set $A$ again *and it still has the elements of $P$ in it*.  Frankly... I don't like the text.

Comment: ok thanks @Jackson and fleablood, I get what you both are trying to say. You saved alot of my time :D

Comment: I suspect that there is a meaningful and reasonable interpretation of the phrase "The set $A$ is reconstructed by replacing the elements of $P$".   The problem that I have is that my best guess as to its meaning would force $P \cap Q$ to equal the empty set.  My example is that $$A = \{1,2,\cdots,100\},~P = \{1,2,\cdots,20\}.$$  I then imagine that $A$ is reconstructed to $A'$, so that $$A' = \{21,22,\cdots,100,101,102,\cdots,120\}.$$  The problem is that in this scenario, since $Q \subseteq A'$ and $A' \cap P$ is the empty set, $Q \cap P$ is the empty set.

Comment: My best guess, from the previous comment, is that the composer of the original problem made an analytical mistake or a mistake in syntax, when composing the problem.